# Scss recursive function for all combination in list with target length

Tags: sass

Can anyone make this function into a recursive general function so that I can use it to retrieve combinations for `n` number of sizes ?

This is what I currently have and it only works until the `$size: 2`

```
@function combinations($list, $size, $separator: comma){
  $result: null;

  @each $item in $list {

    @if ($size == 1) {

      $result: append($result, #{$item}, $separator);
    } @else {

      @each $val in $list {

        $result: join($result, #{$item}#{$val}, $separator);
      }
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}


$list: a, b, c;

test {
  val: combinations($list, 2);
}
```

Output on size: 1

> a, b, c

Output on size: 2

> a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc

But I need this to go on with `$size: n` and `n <= length($list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After multiple attempts and lots of research I finally got a solution.

```
@function combinations($list, $size: length($list), $combs: (), $separator: comma){

  @if ($combs == ()) {
    $combs: $list;
  }

  @if ($size == 1) {

    @return $combs
  }

  $newCombs: null;

  @each $comb in $combs {
    @each $item in $list {
      @if not index($newCombs, $comb) {
        $newCombs: join($newCombs, #{$comb}#{$item}, $separator);
      }
    }
  }

  @return join($combs, #{combinations($list, abs($size - 1), $newCombs)});
}

$list: a, b, c;
$size: n;
```

`combinations($list, $size);` will output a list of all possible combinations of values in `$list` based on `$size`.